# Add a record in Many to many relation fails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a many to many connection in Rails applications, it looks like this:

```
class Workspace
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, dependent: :destroy
end

class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workspaces
end

class UserWorkspace
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :workspace
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table :users_workspaces do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :workspace_id
  t.integer :role, default: 0

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Then I want to create a new record like this:

```
@user.workspaces.create(:workspace_id => @workspace.id, :role => 1)
```

or this

```
@user.workspaces << @workspace
```

and have an error in logs:

```
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 207ms (ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 207ms (ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'workspace_id' for Workspace.):
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `block in sign_up'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:4:in `sign_up'
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS Controller:

```
def sign_up
respond_to do |format|
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    @workspace = Workspace.new(title: "#{@user.name}'s workspace")
    @workspace.save
    puts "workspace id: #{@workspace.id}"
    @user.workspaces.create(:workspace_id => @workspace.id, :role => 1)
    puts "workspaces count: #{@user.workspaces.count}"
    @user.workspace = @workspace
    @user.update_attributes(user_params)

    flash.now[:success] = 'Welcome! Please check activation letter in your email box.'
    format.js { render 'signup_message' }
  else
    format.js { render 'render_signup_errors' }
  end
end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name, :workspace_id)
end
```

Comment: Are your `@user` and `@workspace` object persisted already? Please add your controller code here as well.

Comment: ` def sign_up
    respond_to do |format|
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        @workspace = Workspace.new(title: "#{@user.name}'s workspace")
        @workspace.save
        @user.workspaces.create(:workspace_id => @workspace.id, :role => 1)
        @user.workspace = @workspace
        @user.update_attributes(user_params)

        flash.now[:success] = 'Welcome! Please check activation letter in your email box.'
        format.js { render 'signup_message' }
      else
        format.js { render 'render_signup_errors' }
      end
    end
  end

Comment: sorry for bad format

Comment: I think it's better if you add it into your question body.

Comment: done, I have added it

Comment: sorry, user.workspaces << workspace helped me. It seems when I tried it before, I did not save workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems with your code. For example, you are creating workspaces that are already created (`@user.workspaces.create`), or permitting a `:workspace_id` that is not used, etc.

Pleas see code below:

```
def sign_up
  respond_to do |format|
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save

      @workspace = Workspace.new(title: "#{@user.name}'s workspace")

      if @workspace.save
        # Like this
        UserWorkspace.create(user: @user, workspace: @workspace, role: 1)

        # Or, like this
        @user.user_workspaces.create!(workspace_id: @workspace.id, role: 1)
      end

      flash.now[:success] = 'Welcome! Please check activation letter in your email box.'
      format.js { render 'signup_message' }
    else
      format.js { render 'render_signup_errors' }
    end
  end
end

private

# You don't need :workspace_id since you are not using it anywhere
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name)
end
```